# Why my stored procedure is returning true even it is raising error ?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

Why this SP returns me TRUE even i have mentioned if certain conditions met then it should **raise error** but still it returns true. I have checked conditions and it's meeting but still true, Why ?

SP:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[usp_UpdateWithdrawal]
(
    @NITNo int,
    @WorkNo int,
    @ContractorID int,
    @IsWithDrawn bit
)

AS
BEGIN
    Begin Try

     Begin Transaction

        Declare @ExpiryDate date
        Declare @ExpiryTime time(7)

        Set @ExpiryDate= (Select convert(varchar(11), ExpiryDate, 106) from Works where NIT_No= @NITNo and WorkNo= @WorkNo)
        Set @ExpiryTime= (Select CAST(ExpiryTime as TIME(0)) from Works where NIT_No= @NITNo and WorkNo= @WorkNo)

        IF(CONVERT(varchar(11), @ExpiryDate, 106)+' '+Convert(varchar(8),CAST(@ExpiryTime as TIME(0))) < CONVERT(varchar(11), Getdate(), 106)+' '+Convert(varchar(8),CAST(Getdate() as TIME(0))))       
        Begin
            RAISERROR('Sorry, Expiry Date and Time has passed', 16, 10);
            return;
        End

        Update AppliedWorks
        Set Withdrawn= @IsWithDrawn
        Where NIT_No= @NITNo and Work_No= @WorkNo and Contractor_ID= @ContractorID and 
        CONVERT(varchar(11), @ExpiryDate, 106)+' '+Convert(varchar(8),CAST(@ExpiryTime as TIME(0))) < CONVERT(varchar(11), Getdate(), 106)+' '+Convert(varchar(8),CAST(Getdate() as TIME(0)))

        --Update Hisotry

        Declare @AppliedWorkID int
        Set @AppliedWorkID= (Select AppliedWorkID from AppliedWorks 
                             Where NIT_No= @NITNo and Work_No= @WorkNo and Contractor_ID= @ContractorID)


                Insert into AppliedWorkHistory
                (
                    AppliedWork_ID,
                    FinancialMoney,
                    AboveBelow,
                    EntryDateTime,

                    TwoPercentAmount,
                    TwoPercentBankName,
                    TwoPercentDemandDaftNo,
                    TwoPercentDemandDaftValue,
                    TwoPercentRemarks,

                    EightPercentAmount,
                    EightPercentBankName,
                    EightPercentDemandDaftNo,
                    EightPercentDemandDaftValue,
                    EightPercentRemarks, 
                    IsFinalized,
                    Withdrawn
                )
                Select @AppliedWorkID, aw.FinancialMoney, aw.AboveBelow, Getdate(), aw.TwoPercentAmount, aw.TwoPercentBankName, aw.EightPercentDemandDaftNo,
                       aw.TwoPercentDemandDaftValue, aw.TwoPercentRemarks, aw.EightPercentAmount, aw.EightPercentBankName, 
                       aw.EightPercentDemandDaftNo, aw.EightPercentDemandDaftValue, aw.EightPercentRemarks, aw.IsFinalized, @IsWithDrawn  
                from AppliedWorks aw where aw.AppliedWorkID= @AppliedWorkID



     Commit Transaction

    End Try
    Begin Catch
                Rollback transaction
    End Catch 


END;
```

C#:

public static bool UpdateWithdrawal(int NitNo, int WorkNo, int ContractorID, bool IsWithDrawn)
{
    bool Result;

```
ClsDatabaseManager dbManager = ClsDatabaseManager.InitializeDbManager(Constants.Databases.TendersConnection);
try
{
    dbManager.CreateParameters(4);
    dbManager.AddParameters(0, "@NITNo", NitNo);
    dbManager.AddParameters(1, "@WorkNo", WorkNo);
    dbManager.AddParameters(2, "@ContractorID", ContractorID);
    dbManager.AddParameters(3, "@IsWithDrawn", IsWithDrawn);
    dbManager.Open();
    Result = dbManager.ExecuteNonQuery("usp_UpdateWithdrawal", CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToBool();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    dbManager.Close();
    dbManager.Dispose();
}

return Result;
```

}

Comment: You are raising an error in a `TRY..CATCH` and not handling it in the `CATCH`, you need to throw the error in your `CATCH` section as well

Comment: done thanks a lot. Write your message in answer's box so I can mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted in the comments.

You are raising an error within a `TRY..CATCH` and not handling it in the `CATCH`, you need to throw the error in your `CATCH` section as well.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `return` statement after placed in Raiserror statement.
Because If you use a `tryCatch` block, `Error` throw to catch block.
So After `raiseError` remove return statement in your store procedure.